# Telerik Radgrid Hierarchical

Tags: telerik, radgrid, hierarchical

I have a Telerik RadGrid and have a very simple Hierarchical dataset that I want to display.  I used the code from the Telerik example but it doesn't work.  Does anyone know how to implement a Hierarchical Telerik RadGrid?  Does the relation need to be setup in the dataset as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at their new [TreeList](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx) control? It combines a hierarchical view with a grid. I haven't used it, but it sounds like the kind of thing you may need.

Comment: Sorry - can't help beyond that suggestion - I don't use the grid control. If this new control would solve your problem, maybe you could convince your boss to spring for an upgrade :)

Comment: @Ray....it would definitely work.  I did find a solution, though....I'll post the Answer.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The following [tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-hierarchical-grid-tutorial-binding-to-hierarchical-data.html) gives a full example of binding hierarcical data for RadGridView for WinForms.

Hope that helps
Richard

Comment: @Richard...that does help.  With the exceptin that I am loading the data from a DatSet rather than a database.  I have to create the data on the fly so needed to use the DataSet.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote [this blog entry](http://blogs.telerik.com/robertshoemate/posts/10-10-08/techniques_for_creating_a_hierarchical_radgridview_for_winforms.aspx) a while back about using the various hierarchy modes of RadGridView for WinForms. I hope it helps...